# centos 6.8: Deleted /var/log/messages .... it didn't come back?

Tags: centos, syslog

To make debugging an issue easier, I deleted /var/log/messages .... and it hasn't come back!

I thought debug messages from kernel and modules like autofs were routed to this file.  But even after I cycle autofs (which is set to verbose logging), this file is gone.

How to recover?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to restart your system logger:

```
service rsyslog restart
```

(as `root`).

A reboot would also have the same effect, but it's rather overkill.

Log messages go to a system logger, `rsyslog` on CentOS, and the logger writes to various files depending on its configuration (or even other loggers on remote systems). `rsyslog` opens `/var/log/messages` when it starts, and keeps it open; deleting `/var/log/messages` makes it disappear from the directory, but the file still exists and is usable by any program which had it open. So `rsyslog` continues logging to the deleted file... Restarting it causes it to re-open the file, re-creating it first in this case.

Comment: In my case, on old centos it was service syslog restart ...

Answer (score 0):

A reboot would help: the file is opened (**creating** if it does not exist) at **startup**, and while you can "see" it with `lsof`, it's gone from the filesystem until something opens it again.

Once you get your file back, I suggest proving that nothing else opens it by **renaming** the file.  If any other process creates it, you'll see that when it happens.

Comment: But I have done autofs operations that should get logged there, and the file is not getting created... shouldn't that do it?

Comment: Apparently not - your messages are written to the deleted file by the ongoing process ;-)